# How to reload data from custom view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
```

and

```
class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
```

How to update `CartViewController` from `CartTableViewCell` file

```
class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBAction func buttonDeleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let url = "http://aaaaaa/cart/"+label.text!+"/del"
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer "+token!]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print("delete json ",json)
            let success = json["success"].boolValue
            print(success)
            if success == true{
                //UPDATE CARTVIEWCONTROLLER
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        }

    }
}
```

I looked for similar problems on the Internet but I did not find a suitable explanation

Comment: What is your work flow?? First explain what you wanted to achieve and what you have achieved yet and where you stucked??

Comment: Possible solution is to implement create CartTabelViewCellDelegate, and in the  CartTableViewCell to have property from this delegate. After that to implement this delegate in the CartViewController and on to set the delagte when you are loading the cell.

Comment: Or you can make button action in ViewController then you don't have to worry about this you will have direct access of tableview in completion block, otherwise go by Sh_Khan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a protocol

```
protocol ReloadManager {
  func callReload(cell:CartTableViewCell) 
}
```

//

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,ReloadManager {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"id") as! CartTableViewCell

      cell.delegate = self

    }
    func callReload(cell:CartTableViewCell) {

       cartsTableView.reloadData()

       // use cell if you want to get indexpath to remove item from the table
    }

}
```

//

```
class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   var delegate:ReloadManager?
   func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton){
      delegate?.callReload(cell:self)
   }

}
```